# Is it better to read a file multiple times or save it in a static holder?

Tags: android

I have a list of about 88,000 surnames,
I need to read it every few minutes, so instead I read it once and store it in a list.
It that better or should I read every time.
Memory vs Run-Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It that better or should I read every time

Neither, IMHO. Use a smarter cache.

- Have a static thread-safe cache for this data.
- Design the API around that cache such that the cache can be lazy-loaded. Whoever is seeking to examine the cache should get the results asynchronously, so if the cache is empty, you can load the cache contents on a background thread. This could be accomplished using a listener/callback pattern, RxJava/RxAndroid, `LiveData`, etc.
- Have a custom subclass of `Application`, and in there, [override `onTrimMemory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTrimMemory(int)). If `onTrimMemory()` is called with [a value of `TRIM_MEMORY_BACKGROUND`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#TRIM_MEMORY_BACKGROUND) or higher, empty the cache, so that your memory usage is lower when the user is not actively using your app.

This way, the code using the cache does not care whether the data needs to be loaded or not, and you can minimize memory consumption when it is unlikely that the cache needs to be used.

Or, if you never need all 88,000 surnames in memory at once, store them in a SQLite database and query that database as needed.

Answer (score 0):

In general run-time uses memory so you should be on same. Difference is that you can store in memory as an object and remove it from memory as you need so some memory picks will be present instead of consistent memory load.

Did you consider using API or JavaScript for that logic and load JSON instead?  Approach with different architecture using API or JavaScript as business logic to load JSON might help with loading and unloading object that contains data. JSON can be static stored locally or even dynamic (stored in remote server) which can help with easy update of your surnames. Additionally, this approach can query data as per parameters passed so you might need not to load all 80.0000 surnames at once. I see that question is about Android but architecture approach could be the same for any device.

I hope this might help you or somebody else to determine approach depending on architecture and mobile platform (is not really defined in question if any is used).

Cheers!